# Cakephp order by result set for find

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I change the find query order option so the username comes first for the result?

```
$params = array(
                        'fields' => array('User.firstname', 'User.lastname', 'User.username', 'User.lat', 'User.lng', 'User.thumbnail_image', 'User.status', '6371 * ACos( Cos( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( '.$lat.' ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( '.$lng.' ) - RADIANS( User.lng ) ) + Sin( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Sin( RADIANS( '.$lat.' ) ) ) as distance'),
                        'limit' => 15,
                        'recursive' => 1,
                        'offset' => $offset,
                        'order' => array('User.status DESC','User.lastname ASC', 'distance ASC')
                        //'conditions' => array('User.id !=' => $user_id)
                        );
                $results = $this->User->find('all', $params);
```

I've got this so far but cannot seem to change it so a certain user(1 user) comes in the first row of results.

Is there a solution for this in Cakephp?

Comment: you mean you want to show a specific user in first row... or want to order by username..?

Comment: I want specific user in the first row

Comment: What exactly you want ? How exactly you want to sort your result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw SQL you need might look like:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN User.id = 200
  THEN 0 
  ELSE 1  END as user_sort, ... rest, of, your, params
ORDER BY user_sort, ... rest, of, your, ordering, criteria
LIMIT 15
```

In CakePHP you should use a virtual field to create the user_sort and then just add it to your order array.

In your user model add a virtual field for user_sort:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
        'user_sort' => 'if( User.id  = 200 , 0 , 1)'    
);
```

Then you would add to your order array like so:

```
array('User.user_sort','User.status DESC','User.lastname ASC', 'distance ASC')
```

Comment: great! but how would you include this as part of find params in controller? The reason is that I need to have User.id dynamic based on find.. ie: "if(User.id = "